# how to combine SearchQuery using & operator in Django postgres for uncertain multiple keywords comming from form field

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a form that has two fields (title, skills) that takes keywords separated by commas. and we want to provide a search for all the skills using `SearchQuery` and `'&'` operator. so if my `search_vector` is `SearchVector('job_title',)` and suppose user is looking for Ex. Java,python,.net
as skills we can write our query something like..

`PostedJobReq.objects.annotate(search=search_vector).filter(SearchQuery('java') & SearchQuery('python') & SearchQuery('.net'))` should and does give us result.

But my case is that we are getting keywords like Ex. Java,python,.net from `Formfield` so

1. we don't know how many keywords user is going to search for.
2. and what are those keywords going to be.

so how am i suppose to concatenate multiple `SearchQueries` together when i don't even how many keywords user is going to search for..
I successfully made a list of all the `SearchQueries` but i am not able to concatenate them using `&` module in the code.

views.py

[image]

complexadvsearch.html This is how my template looks and holding a search form

[image]

Models.py  this is how my models look like, Simple some job titles and some Major skills used in that

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and change all the pictures of code to be text instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine SearchQuery() objects like this:

```
if filters:
    my_filter = SearchQuery(filters.pop())

    for f in filters:
        my_filter |= SearchQuery(f)
```

just like with Q() objects:

```
my_filter = Q()

for f in filters:
    my_filter &= Q(something=f)
```

and then

```
Stuff.objects.filter(f)
```

This is a really cool part of the Django ORM.

But if all your conditionals use `&` you don't need to use the `Q` object at all.

Just do:

```
filter_list = [SearchQuery(i) for i in filters]
Stuff.objects.filter(*filter_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It did the job!